# wxPython, Triggering an Event While Dragging

Tags: python, events, binding, wxpython

I have a window, and when the window changes position I'd like an event to be triggered. How do I go about this in wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by listening to the EVT_MOVE event.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove)
```

and

```
def OnMove(self, event):
    print event.GetPosition()
```